# can't cout data from the head of a linked list outside of my add function

Tags: c++, linked-list

So i've been teaching myself linked lists and been messing around trying to write some very basic functions for them. Basically what i've been working with

```
struct ListNode{
int data;
ListNode *next
};
```

I'm trying to make a function to add numbers to a list and what i've gotten so far is

```
void addToList(int numberToAdd, struct ListNode *headOfList){
ListNode *newItem=new ListNode;
newItem->data=numberToAdd;
if(headOfList==NULL){
    newItem->next=NULL;
    headOfList=newItem;
}}
```

So far i've only tried to add a single ListNode to an empty list declared as

```
ListNode *head=NULL;
```

in my main function. the problem that i'm having is that after I do my

```
addToList(someRandomNumber,head);
```

I get an error if I do this,

```
cout<<head->data;
```

but if I go into my addToList function and do

```
cout<<headOfList->data;
```

it works perfectly fine. Why is this so?

Comment: `headOfList=newItem;` only modifies the local pointer, so the reference is lost. You need to modify the value of the pointer to head.

Comment: The error is Access violation reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`headOfLst` is being passed by value so when you modify the variable it is not being reflected in `main`:

```
void addToList(int numberToAdd, struct ListNode *headOfList){
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you pass it has a double pointer you will be able to modify the pointer itself:

```
void addToList(int numberToAdd, struct ListNode **headOfList){
```

then the assignment later on would be:

```
*headOfList=newItem;
```

**Edit**

and the call in `main` should be modified like so:

```
addtolist(1,&head);
```

Another option, is to pass a reference to a pointer:

```
void addToList(int numberToAdd, struct ListNode *& headOfList){
                                                 ^
```

no other code has to be modified in that case.

Comment: Ok so.. I did this and now I dont know how to modify what i have in my main function
I had something like
addtolist(1,head);
it says it can't convert ListNode * to ListNode** (i am very new at this :*() my ignorance probably makes you want to cry

Comment: @MichaelKiminChoo, `addtolist(1,&head);`

Comment: @MichaelKiminChoo I apologize, I left my house before I realized I left that part out. I updated my post and added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to accept your answer till now too and you're educating me for free so no apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your `headList` argument to `addToList` you are actually passing a **copy** of it. `headOfList` and `head` are independent pointers. This means that when you modify your head pointer inside the function to point to anything else and return, the `head` pointer **is still unmodified** (pointing to NULL). When you execute `cout<<head->data;`, you are dereferencing a NULL pointer. (`head->data` is equal to `(*head).data`.)

The solution in this case is to add another level of indirection, that is, pass a pointer to a pointer to a `ListNode`, as Shafik explains:

```
addToList(someRandomNumber, &head);
```